# How should we repent for masturbation, formerly being homosexual, bisexual, or crossdresser?

Tags: homosexuality, tawba, masturbation

How should we repent for masturbation, formerly being homosexual, bisexual, or crossdresser? Is praying 2 rakats and not committing the same sin is enough, or should we do more to fully repent?

Comment: No, praying 2 rak'aats and sincerely repenting from the sin and not returning to it again is just enough, unless the sin needs a ransom to be repented from. An important thing is to have faith in Allah that he will forgive you (if you really sincerely repented).

Comment: @Hudaverdi, what Abdel Rahman remarked, seems true. As a brief explanation of that (AFAIK): Repent: Asking Allah for the forgiveness (AstaghferollahRabi-wa-Atoobo-Elih...), decide really not to repeat that sin again. And paying damages if ...

Comment: Related: [Does the process of repentance differ significantly based on the sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/41427/17163)